# In typescript, how to acces to variable in window function?

Tags: typescript

I would like to emit a new value to my BehaviourSubject when Google Maps Api has been loaded, but I cannot acces to class parameters, code:

```
private isInitialized = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  private initialization() {
    // Load Google Maps Api script
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + environment.googlePlaces.apiKey + '&libraries=places&callback=initMap';
    script.async = true;

    window['initMap'] = function () { debugger; this.isInitialized.next(true); }
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }
```

I enter in debugger, but *this* is associated to something else than the class.

How can I connect *this* to the instance of my class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thanks :) When I made a search, I didn't find the answer with my words, I shared the solution bellow.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
window['initMap'] = function() { debugger; this.isInitialized.next(true); }
```

by:

```
 window['initMap'] = () => { debugger; this.isInitialized.next(true); }
```